# Code formating is broken for one of ouer projects but only on github

Tags: github, formatting

I noticed in a pull request from a colleague the formatting was off, we dobbel checked his local repo and all looked ok on his end.

I tried doing a small change pushed and still same issue, anyone seen anything like this?

File open in vs2022

[image: local cs file]

Same file at github

[image: Github cs file]

one more exsamlpe same repo,, diffrent random file
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

template code seems to use tabs, and all the lines we have touched comes with .... (4spaces)

this seems to break on the github side. case closed.

[image]